# Flutter API Requests using Streams - Too many elements

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

coming with a bit of a tricky one. :slight_smile: We opted out using the `http` [library](https://pub.dev/packages/http), instead using the `HttpClient` [class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-io/HttpClient-class.html) directly, because it gives us more control over the client, and headers etc. The `http package` wraps that class anyway. The class returns streams.

Using

```
Flutter 1.20.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 216dee60c0 (6 days ago) • 2020-09-01 12:24:47 -0700
Engine • revision d1bc06f032
Tools • Dart 2.9.2
```

Function that is called in our services to fetch data from backend api (names a bit alternated):

```
  static Future<String> APIRequest(
      {@required String relativeURL,
      @required String method,
      @required EnvironmentConfig config,
      dynamic data,
      HttpClient httpClient,
      Map<String, String> queryParameters}) async {
    final stream = await _APIRequest(
        method: method,
        relativeURL: relativeURL,
        httpClient: httpClient,
        data: data,
        queryParameters: queryParameters,
        config: config);
    return stream.singleWhere((obj) => obj != null, orElse: () => '');
  }
```

Underlying private API request function:

```
  static Future<Stream<String>> _APIRequest(
      {@required String method,
      @required EnvironmentConfig config,
      @required String relativeURL,
      Map<String, String> queryParameters,
      HttpClient httpClient,
      dynamic data,
      String token}) async {
    final client = httpClient == null ? HttpClient() : httpClient;
    final url =
        UriService.getUri(config, relativeURL, queryParameters);
    final request = await client.openUrl(method, url);
    // Add headers
    request.headers.add(
        "X-MOBILE-APP", 'test'); // The value is ignore by the backend
    if (token != null) {
      request.headers.add(HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader, 'Token $token');
    }
   if (data != null) {
      final encodedData = json.encode(data, toEncodable: _toEncodable);
      request.headers.contentType = ContentType.json;
      request.headers.contentLength = utf8.encode(encodedData).length;
      request.write(encodedData);
    }
    final response = await request.close();
    await _rejectIfBadStatusCode(response);
    return utf8.decoder.bind(response);
  }
```

Using this approach works well for most of the time, but now we have recently encountered a lot of  `E/flutter (13551): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Too many elements` Any idea if this has to do with the streams or similar?

Here is the stacktrace:

```
E/flutter (13551): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Too many elements
E/flutter (13551): #0      Stream.singleWhere.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/stream.dart:1508:15)
E/flutter (13551): #1      _runUserCode  (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:11:14)
E/flutter (13551): #2      Stream.singleWhere.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/stream.dart:1504:7)
E/flutter (13551): #3      _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter (13551): #4      _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (13551): #5      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (13551): #6      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:357:11)
E/flutter (13551): #7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:285:7)
E/flutter (13551): #8      _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._add  (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:69:11)
E/flutter (13551): #9      _EventSinkWrapper.add  (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:15:11)
E/flutter (13551): #10     _StringAdapterSink.add  (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:238:11)
E/flutter (13551): #11     _StringAdapterSink.addSlice  (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:243:7)
E/flutter (13551): #12     _Utf8ConversionSink.addSlice  (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:317:20)
E/flutter (13551): #13     _Utf8ConversionSink.add  (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:310:5)
E/flutter (13551): #14     _ConverterStreamEventSink.add  (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:72:18)
E/flutter (13551): #15     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData  (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:121:24)
E/flutter (13551): #16     _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter (13551): #17     _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (13551): #18     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (13551): #19     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:357:11)
E/flutter (13551): #20     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:285:7)
E/flutter (13551): #21     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._add  (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:69:11)
E/flutter (13551): #22     _EventSinkWrapper.add  (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:15:11)
E/flutter (13551): #23     _Uint8ListConversionSink.add  (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:572:13)
E/flutter (13551): #24     _ConverterStreamEventSink.add  (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:72:18)
E/flutter (13551): #25     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData  (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:121:24)
E/flutter (13551): #26     _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter (13551): #27     _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (13551): #28     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (13551): #29     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:357:11)
E/flutter (13551): #30     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:285:7)
E/flutter (13551): #31     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._add  (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:69:11)
E/flutter (13551): #32     _EventSinkWrapper.add  (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:15:11)
E/flutter (13551): #33     _ByteAdapterSink.add  (dart:convert/byte_conversion.dart:58:11)
E/flutter (13551): #34     _FilterSink.addSlice  (dart:io/data_transformer.dart:615:15)
E/flutter (13551): #35     _FilterSink.add  (dart:io/data_transformer.dart:597:5)
E/flutter (13551): #36     _ConverterStreamEventSink.add  (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:72:18)
E/flutter (13551): #37     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData  (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:121:24)
E/flutter (13551): #38     _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter (13551): #39     _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (13551): #40     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (13551): #41     CastStreamSubscription._onData  (dart:_internal/async_cast.dart:85:11)
E/flutter (13551): #42     _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter (13551): #43     _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (13551): #44     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (13551): #45     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:357:11)
E/flutter (13551): #46     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:285:7)
E/flutter (13551): #47     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add  (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:127:11)
E/flutter (13551): #48     _HandleErrorStream._handleData  (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:266:10)
E/flutter (13551): #49     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData  (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:157:13)
E/flutter (13551): #50     _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter (13551): #51     _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (13551): #52     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (13551): #53     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (da
```